# AWS spot fleet terraform request subnet(s)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, amazon-ecs

Trying to learn spot fleet for ECS cluster. I'm using default VPC and and default subnets for it.

```
data "aws_vpc" "default" {
  default = true
}

data "aws_subnet_ids" "all_subnets" {
  vpc_id = data.aws_vpc.default.id
}
```

Having trouble with subnet assign to spot fleet `launch_specification`.
Have so far was trying subnet id with different approaches:

```
resource "aws_spot_fleet_request" "main" {
  iam_fleet_role                      = aws_iam_role.spot_fleet.arn
  target_capacity                     = 6
  spot_price                          = "0.03"
  allocation_strategy                 = "diversified"
  terminate_instances_with_expiration = true

  launch_specification {
    ami                    = data.aws_ami.amazon_linux_2_ecs_optimized.id
    instance_type          = "c3.large"
    spot_price             = "0.03"
    subnet_id              = data.aws_subnet_ids.all_subnets.id[0]
    subnet_id              = data.aws_subnet_ids.all_subnets.ids[0]
    subnet_id              = data.aws_subnet_ids.all_subnets.*.ids[0]
    vpc_security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.ecs_ec2.id]
    iam_instance_profile   = aws_iam_instance_profile.ecs_instance_profile.name
    key_name               = "FrankfurtRegion"

    root_block_device {
      volume_type = "gp2"
      volume_size = 10
    }

    user_data = data.template_file.user_data.rendered
  }... snip ... below other 2 launch_specifications...
```

Getting erroros every time and cant spin up fleet. If you have or know about good exaple of spining ecs with spot fleet, asg and launch template would be great to see that.
As always help please.

edit: Errors from code:

1. `Error requesting spot fleet: Error creating Spot fleet request, retrying: InvalidSpotFleetRequestConfig: One of the provided subnets was not valid.` for option with data.aws_subnet_ids.all_subnets.*.id[0]
2. Two other syntaxes give me `Error: Invalid index`

Comment: What error are you receiving?

Comment: `Error requesting spot fleet: Error creating Spot fleet request, retrying: InvalidSpotFleetRequestConfig: One of the provided subnets was not valid.` for option with `data.aws_subnet_ids.all_subnets.*.id[0]`, two other syntaxes give me `Error: Invalid index`

Comment: You should edit your question to include the error.

Comment: Done the edit, hope that is clear now.